# Print a different result than actual answer (Ciel and A-B Problem)

Tags: c

**Input:**
An input contains 2 integers A and B.

**Output:**
Print a wrong answer of A-B. Your answer must be a positive integer containing the same number of digits as the correct answer, and exactly one digit must differ from the correct answer. Leading zeros are not allowed. If there are multiple answers satisfying the above conditions, anyone will do.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int no_of_zeroes(int x);

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    int res1, res2;
    int n1, n2;

    scanf("%d",&a);
    scanf("%d",&b);
    res1 = a - b;
    res2 = res1 + 10;
    n1 = no_of_zeroes(res1);
    n2 = no_of_zeroes(res2);

    if(res1 < 9) printf("%d",res1 + 1);
    else if(res1 == 9) printf("%d",res1-1); 
    else if((n1 == n2) && (res1 > 9)) printf("%d",res2);
    else if((n2 > n1) && (res1>9))
    {
        res2 = res2 - 20;
        printf("%d",res2);
    }    
}

int no_of_zeroes(int x)
{
    int count = 0;
    while(x>0)
    {
        x = x / 10;
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

**Error:**
What different should i do, basically else if blocks are creating trouble.

Comment: `no_of_zeroes` doesn't seem to **count zeros**. And why would you want to count zeros?

Comment: The condition `0 <= res1 < 9` is really `(0 <= res1) < 9` (IIRC). That is, you compare the result of the comparison `0 <= res1` to check if it's less than `9`. And the result of a comparison will always be true (which is `1`) or false (which is `0`). And both `1` and `0` are less than `9`, so the condition will *always* be true. Please read some about the logical operators AND `&&` and OR `||`.

Comment: sorry it count number of digits

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i changed the condition to if (res1<9) still solution is not accepted

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger and how to use it to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. When stepping through code it also helps understand what's going on if you don't have multiple statements on the same line, so please put each statement on a separate line.

Comment: From the looks of it, if the number is less than or equal to 9 you have it handled ok. If it isn't then you're adding or subtracting  1 from the second digit. What if the answer has 3 digits? Eg. 195? Then you check 195 + 10 = 205. It has the same length as 195, but two digits vary. Why do you change the second digit, why not always change the first digit? Do you know what the modulo operator is?

Comment: the function no_of_zeroes() should return 1 when x=0. however, I think it can be solved without counting the number of digits. all you need to do is add 1 to the difference. but if the last digit of the difference is 9, you should subtract 1 instead of adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your answer must be a positive integer containing the same number of digits as the correct answer

So the answer should be `a-b`. But the statement also says

> exactly one digit must differ from the correct answer

Since it didn't specify the position of the digit, changing the last digit only should give us the correct answer to this problem. And so counting the number of digits of the difference is redundant.

Now the issue is - how to change the last digit? It's simple. We add 1 to the difference.

But there is a catch! If the difference is 99 and we add 1 to it, the result will be 100. Here, not only we're changing more than one digit, but also the number of digits.

And so, all we have to do is subtract 1 from the difference if the last digit of the difference is 9.

And so, the if-else block should look something like this:

```
int diff = a - b;
if(diff%10 == 9) {
    diff--;
}
else {
    diff++;
}
```

Here's my full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    int diff = a - b;
    if(diff%10 == 9) {
        diff--;
    }
    else {
        diff++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", diff);
    return 0;
}
```

On a different note, the function `no_of_zeroes(int x)` will return 0 if x=0. But, it should return 1 under general circumstances. And so the function should be something like this:

```
int no_of_digits(int x)
{
    /* Adding the following line should fix the issue */
    if(x==0) return 1;

    int count = 0;
    while(x>0)
    {
        x = x / 10;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't handle this requirement: "Your answer must be a positive integer" but that should be easy to fix ;-)

Comment: @4386427 here's the [full description](https://www.codechef.com/problems/CIELAB). According to the statement a>b.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making this much more complicated than needed. All you need is to check the last digit of the correct result and then change it.

For 0 and positive numbers:

```
 last digit is 0 : add 1
 last digit is 1 : add 1
 ...
 last digit is 8 : add 1
 last digit is 9 : subtract 1
```

For negative numbers, you simply change the sign and handle it as the positive number. This can be done because `-123` has the same digits as `123`.

So the code can be:

```
void wrongCalc(int a, int b)
{
    int res = a - b;           // Calculate result
    if (res < 0) res = -res;   // Change sign if negative
    int lastDigit = res % 10;  // Find last digit
    if (lastDigit == 9)
    {
        --res;    // Subtract 1
    }
    else
    {
        ++res;    // Add 1
    }

    printf("%d - %d = %d (correct result is %d)\n", a, b, res, a-b);
}
```

Limitations:

1) The program doesn't handle the possible integer overflow in `a-b`

2) The program doesn't handle the possible integer overflow in `res = -res;`

3) The program doesn't handle the case where the correct result is INT_MAX